# Prove that $x^{p^n-1}-1 =\prod\limits_{\alpha\in\mathbb{F}^\times_{p^n}} (x-\alpha)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Exercise 13.5.6 (Dummit & Foote): Prove that $x^{p^n-1}-1 =\prod\limits_{\alpha\in\mathbb{F}^\times_{p^n}} (x-\alpha)$.

How would I go about this? From what I have seen online they begin with $x^{p^n}-x$, I'm not really sure why they start with that. Any help with the whole problem will be appreciated.

Comment: Start from the question of which $\alpha$ satisfy $\alpha\in\mathbb{F}^\times_{p^n}$.

Comment: There are some helpful posts about this topic, e,g, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241931/how-do-i-prove-that-xpn-x-is-the-product-of-all-monic-irreducible-polynomi). The answer also depends on what you already know and which can be assumed without proof. So you should give more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* $\mathbb{F}^\times_{p^n}$ is a multiplicative group of order $p^n-1$.
By Lagrange's theorem, $\alpha^{p^n-1}=1$ for all $\alpha \in\mathbb{F}^\times_{p^n}$.